# Express server using TypeScript and Typings

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'm trying to set up an express web server using TypeScript, but get this error every time I attempt to transpile to JS

`error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.`

I'm a newbie, and this is what I've done (using WebStorm). I installed the following express ambient dependency using typings, i.e.,

`typings install --ambient --save express`

which created the following typings.json file

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160317120654",
  }
}
```

looking at the `index.d.ts` file in `typings\main\ambient\express\`, WebStorm complains that it can't find the modules `serve-static`, `express-serve-static-core` and `mime`. So I installed those, along with node, such that `typings.json` becomes

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160317120654",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#0.0.0+20160322035842",
    "mime": "registry:dt/mime#0.0.0+20160316155526",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515",
    "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#0.0.0+20160501131543"
  }
}
```

I then added a the following `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "server.ts"
  ]
}
```

I installed the express module from npm such that my `package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "using-typings",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "mime": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and created `server.ts` as follows

```
/** Created by James on 5/12/2016. */
/// <reference path="typings/main.d.ts"/>
import express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Now attempting to transpile this using `tsc server.ts`I get the following errors

```
\using-typings>tsc server.ts
\using-typings\server.ts(4,1): error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.
\using-typings\server.ts(4,8): error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.
\using-typings\server.ts(4,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
\using-typings\server.ts(4,21): error TS1005: ';' expected.
\using-typings\server.ts(4,26): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

I'm obviously missing something, but can't figure it out. Any advice please?

Comment: The errors you are listing are on line 4. Can you post your entire server.ts file?

Comment: Edited the question adding the top two lines to server.ts

Comment: Letting WebStorm do the compilation seems to work. But typing `tsc server.ts` at the command line throws the errors shown above.

Comment: typing `tsc -v` at the command line reports a version number of 1.0.3.0. WebStorm appears to use a bundled version 1.8.7. Are these different compilers?

Comment: Yes they are different. Definitely update typescript. Version 1.0.3 is almost 2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't realised that there was an existing install of Typescript with the Microsoft SDK for Visual Studio. Removing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\` from the system environment variables enabled me to use the later version of the typescript compiler installed via node.